# How the working directory is updated on "git checkout"?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Consider the following "story":

```
$ mkdir my_project
$ cd my_project
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/misha/misha/my_project/.git/

$ echo "first line" > hello.txt
$ git add hello.txt
$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) 9c913a1] first commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt

$ git branch new_feature
$ git checkout new_feature
Switched to branch 'new_feature'
$ echo "second line" >> hello.txt
$ cat hello.txt
first line
second line

$ git checkout master
M    hello.txt
Switched to branch 'master'
$ cat hello.txt
first line
second line
```

Why `hello.txt` has two lines on branch *master*? (I thought that `git checkout` will revert the working directory to the previous state, i.e. `hello.txt` will have only one line.)

What actually happens behind the scenes to the working directory on `git checkout`? How it is updated?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your git checkout to master prevents you from losing uncommitted changes. Thats why you still have your second line in your `hello.txt` file. If you really want to lose your uncommitted changes you have to use the `-f` parameter.

Finally your checkout would look like this:

```
git checkout -f master
```

Comment: Same behavior if the file was added to the index but not committed.

Comment: I think branches only store commits, not working changes. When you switch to a branch and do some work, you need to commit those changes before switching to a different branch, or those changes won't be associated with that branch.

Another way to handle branches is to clone your repository into a new directory. Then you can work on the two branches in the two different directories without having to commit until you are ready. This makes it easier to avoid mistakes.

Comment: This doesn't explain the things "actually happens behind the scenes" when checking out a branch.

Answer (score 2):

Git checkout (loosely) will update the working copy with the contents of the repository at the commit which specify. Your `new_feature` branch doesn't have the second line which you've added to your file (since you haven't committed it yet). Right now, that extra line is just an untracked change in your working copy and it will get added to the branch on which you commit it.

Comment: If `git checkout` updates the working directory with the contents of the repository at the commit which I specify (_master_ in my case), and there is only one line in `hello.txt` on the _master_ branch, then on `git checkout master` I would expect `hello.txt` in the working directory to have only one line (exactly like on the _master_ branch). What am I missing here?

Comment: The fact that you have local uncommitted changes in your working directory. If the checkout will overwrite those changes, git will warn you and refuse to switch branches.

Comment: If those changes don't conflict with master then git will just bring those changes over into master's working directory (but it will let you switch branches). This is what OP is experiencing. If those changes conflicted with master then it would not let you switch. Finally if working directory is clean on checkout, it will update working directory to master. This answer leaves out too much information to be correct. In addition, since the OP already stated that the working directory is NOT clean, this answer fails to address that scenario.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Loosely?

Comment: Can't remember why I typed that in there.

Answer (score 0):

Git will checkout as expected if adding second line had been committed to new_feature. 
Uncommitted changes normally prevent from checkout but here it is a merge.

Answer (score -1):

Git checkout doesn't replace the files in your filesystem.
Git checkout changes the branch you're on.
Changing branch doesn't change what's on your filesystem.
I like to think the tree looks like this:

1. Remote repo
   1.a. Master
   1.b. Feature
2. Local repo
   2.a. Master
   2.b. Feature
3. Uncommitted code / filesystem

Checkout -> switch between a nd b

Pull -> copy new unsynchronized stuff in the current branch from 1 to 2

Push -> copy from new stuff in the current branch from 2 to 1

Commit -> copy new stuff from 3 to 2

Comment: I don't think it's true that "checkout doesn't replace the files in your filesystem". Checkout does replace the working directory with the content of the branch, except for modified files.